# 4k monitor isn't giving me the option for UHD

Tags: display, 4k-resolution

I just bot a 4k monitor and i have a Nvidia Quadro k1200 that supposed to support 4 4K monitors at once. I have 4 monitors running at the same time. But the new 4k monitor, I still can't select a higher resolution than Full HD. I also installed the quadro drivers again and restarted the computer. didn't work.

It does look better up close even on Full HD. the other Full HD monitors i can see pixels up close. this one, i can't.

Comment: which type of cable are you using? If you're using HDMI then you need an HDMI 1.3 cable for 4K@30fps and 2.0+ for 4K@60fps

Comment: thanks. that did it. I switched the connector from DVI -> HDMI to displayport and windows automatically set the right settings.